# Accesing method of another class from vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have parent class

```
class Data
{
};
```

Classes that inherit from class Data:

```
class Struct : public Data
{
  public:
  Struct & AddNewType ( const string & name, Data * x )
  {
     v . push_back ( x );
     return *this;
  }

  void Print ( void ) const
  {
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < v . size (); i++ )
      cout << v[i]->GetSize();
  }

  private:
    vector<Data*> v;
};

class Integer : public Data
{
  public:
    int GetSize ( void ) const
    {
      return 4;
    }
};
```

main function :

```
int main ( void )
{
  Struct  a;
  a . AddNewType ( "Integer", new Integer );
  a . Print ();
  return 0;
}
```

When i call `a.Print()` it gives me this error:

```
practice.cpp: In member function ‘void Struct::Print() const’:
practice.cpp:40:21: error: ‘class Data’ has no member named ‘GetSize’
       cout << v[i]->GetSize();
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix that please? The main purpose is just to store different pseudo data types in vector. But when i want to loop vector with those data types and call function GetSize from it it gives me error i posted above.

Comment: It looks like you need a [lesson](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm) on polymorphism.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes i do

Comment: Please don't use preceding or trailing whitespaces with `.` or `->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vector v` stores objects of the type `Data*`. 
However, your `Data` class does not implement the `GetSize()` method, and thus the compiler (correctly) errors because this method does not exist.

It does not matter that your subclasses implement it, since the compiler does not know if you are passing a subclass or the base class.

You should add the `GetSize()` method to your Data class, i.e.

```
class Data {
    public:
        virtual int GetSize() const = 0;
}
```

This also forces child-classes to implement the GetSize() method. If you want to provide a default behaviour, you could provide a default implementation, i.e.

```
class Data {
    public:
        virtual int GetSize() const { return 0; };
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks it works but what if i had a private vector in Integer class and would want to acces that vector like this method? I dont want that vector to be in clas Data class as protected is there any other method?

Comment: You can override the GetSize() method in your integer class and then access that private vector. I really do recommend reading some tutorial about polymorphism though